# DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object with options kwarg

Tags: python, selenium, desktop-application, windows-10-desktop, winium

I'm relatively new to Winium (1.6.0.0) , Selenium (4.1.3) and Python (3.10.2).
I want to automate a simple app like calculator
I implemented some suggested code but it's for an older version of Selenium

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
os.startfile(r'c:\\test\\winium.desktop.driver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:9999', desired_capabilities={'app': "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe","args": '-port 345'})
```

I get the following error from Pycharm:

```
DeprecationWarning: desired_capabilities has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object with options kwarg*
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:9999', desired_capabilities={'app': "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe","args": '-port 345'})
```

How do I update the code to use an Options object instead?

thanks

I tried adjusting the options, but I am uncertain to what options I should be using to test a windows application